# Postdoctoral fellowships/calls to work in Europe for scientists/mathematicians/engineers that are similar to Marie curie?

Tags: postdocs, europe, science

I was wondering where I can find any information on the postdoctoral fellowships/calls to work in Europe which are similar to Marie Curie? I'm doing my
basic internet search on this, but don't seem to succeed that much. I'm especially talking about the fellowships that are offered in the areas of pure or applied sciences or engineering areas.

Any information, site or blog that you know of, I'd greatly appreciate if you could please pass it onto me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For life sciences:

1. [HFSP](http://www.hfsp.org/) Long Term Fellowships and Cross Disciplinary Fellowships. CDF is aimed at people from other disciplines that want to enter biology.
2. [EMBO](http://www.embo.org/funding-awards/fellowships/long-term-fellowships) Long Term Fellowships.
3. [LSRF](http://lsrf.org/) fellowships.

Comment: My sincere appreciation to Bitwise and Federico, that was the kind of answers I was looking for. I'm hoping I could get more to add to the list.

Comment: I think that the EMBO is only for molecular biology, and the HFSP has also a pretty narrow definition of fields it support. For example, they do not support applied project in biotechnology, environmental studies, ecological studies. If somebody is not sure, it is better to contact the fellowship office.

Answer (score 5):

Listing what I know, but it won't be a complete answer for sure.

Germany has several opportunities for foreigners, including [DAAD](https://www.daad.org/) and [Humboldt fellowships](http://www.humboldt-foundation.de/web/start.html).

Italy has launched this year for the first time a call with name [SIR](http://sir.miur.it/); it is now closed, but maybe it will be renewed.

All of them are generalist calls, not aimed at a particular field.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the open academic positions, including postdoc positions, in Switzerland are listed on the [ETH-get-hired](http://www.eth-gethired.ch/search/sector/0/academic/1) website. Although somewhat more popular in German-speaking Switzerland and for Science/Engineering it is fairly general in scope.

I should note that these are typically fully funded job offers, not grants.

Answer (score 1):

There are literally zillions of scholarships.

Contact the representative of EU and the embassies of countries you are interested in. They always have an S&T department which generally have advertisement of such scholarships, websites, or even newsletters on this very topic.

Assuming  that you are in the US, you can contact the MIT European Career Fair (https://www.euro-career.com/) they have several connections to national frameworks like DAAD or Humbold.

Comment: Greg: thanks for your reply, but I'm in EU. But I guess the suggestion remains unchanged even for EU.

Comment: Well it helps if you clarify such details about yourself. :) Yet, it doesn't hurt to check their website and see who are the major scholar sponsors going there.

Answer (score 1):

The European commission hosts a database called EURAXESS on research fellowships that are being offered within the European Union, at all levels (European funding, international funding, national funding). You can easily narrow down searches by these levels and career stage. The link is:

http://ec.europa.eu/euraxess/index.cfm/jobs/index